# Guides for clients to learn to save files to online cloud storage

Tags: difficult-client, communication, client-support, project-management

Every once in a while, I get a client who keeps sending me files over text and email and all kinds of other means.

It becomes a mess and when I bring up that it takes 20 minutes to find all the files - when I ask them yet again to please put the files on Dropbox, they say

Client:

> I don't know how to use a dropbox?  My assistant uses it but I'm not sure how to use it?

Considering this snarky reply:

> You just drag and drop it in box. Probably cheaper for you to ask your secretary

However, maybe the client really needs help.

Are there standard guides to forward to clients to get them to use Dropbox or any other centralized online file sharing/storage?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

I consider it part of my job to make it as easy as possible for clients to send me anything. The *last thing* I want to do is make it uncomfortable or unusual for any client to send me anything.

I may suggest DropBox, Hightail, my own guest FTP access server, email.. but if any of the suggestions are met with resistance I drop it immediately and accept that the client will use the method they prefer.

I, personally, do not think pushing a specific delivery methods is conducive to continued client relations. I would rather deal with the minor organizational issues certain delivery methods may present for me.

Comment: so, the problem is there are several people on the project, including some associates on the client's side.. file confusion seems to add up to a lot of time and the client has a limited budget.

Comment: Well I'd then request all the clients associates use one method, whatever that method is. I'd express that in order to properly organize and track files everyone needs to transfer files using the same method so nothing is overlooked. The problem with Dropbox for some is that it's software installation and configuring. That's above and beyond what some clients want to do. Things like Bitbucket.com may be a better alternative since it's more of a straight signup without software installation. (of course, nature of the files makes a difference).

Comment: so, i've mentioned several times, please let's choose a centralized cloud storage - how about dropbox. Nth time, client finally responds with message above. 

files are misc images and text. this is a non-technical client. (when is dropbox not automagical works-out-of-the-box?)

Comment: Okay.. well arguing with me rather than your client isn't going to help you. If the client doesn't want to use Dropbox.. you can't force them to.

Comment: i guess my question is about how to instruct a client to use cloud storage - preferably a link/tutorial i could send them

Comment: (surprised there is not an easily google-able standard resource)